# Nodejs tools for VS2015 with local dependencies

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build a node js [project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node) with NodeJS tools for VS2015.

In this solution, there is a main project that has sub-projects in sub folders, i.e. each sub-folder has their own package.json with its own code and each one declares their own dependencies to other projects.

The problem I have is that when I do "npm install" in the main project, "npm" downloads the packages from npm registry.

I know that could use:

```
"dependencies": {
    "common": "file:path/to/common",
}
```

But this approach forces me to manually maintain two package.json files and rename it on every commit (the project is open source, on github); It is cumbersome and error prone.

My question is: Can I configure the NodeJS tools for VS to handle two different configurations for debug and release? i.e. In a similar way that I can do it in a C# project.

Something like using a `package.Debug.json` file... any other approach is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it, you can use [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) for create a link between the package and its source code (This post about that is very interesting: [npm link: developing your own npm modules without tears](http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears))

In your case:

- Execute `npm link` for each subproject
- In main project, execute `npm link subproject1` ... `npm link subprojectN`

I have tested it with **Visual Studio 2015** creating a solution with two projects

```
nodejs-projectdeps
|- nodejs-projectdeps-main
|- nodejs-projectdeps-module1
```

package.json for **nodejs-projectdeps-main**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-projectdeps-main",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "nodejs-projectdeps-main",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "azure": "^0.10.6",
    "nodejs-projectdeps-module1": "0.0.0"
  }
}
```

package.json for **nodejs-projectdeps-module1**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-projectdeps-module1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "nodejs-projectdeps-module1",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dockerctl": "0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Then I executed `npm link` in the `nodejs-projectdeps-module1` project folder and the result was:

```
C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\nodejs-projectdeps-module1 
  -> C:\src\nodejs-projectdeps\nodejs-projectdeps-module1
```

After I executed `npm link in the nodejs-projectdeps-module1` project folder and the result was:

```
C:\src\nodejs-projectdeps-main\node_modules\nodejs-projectdeps-module1 
  -> C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\nodejs-projectdeps-module1 
    -> C:\src\nodejs-projectdeps\nodejs-projectdeps-module1
```

After all, the solution in **Visual Studio 2015** shows the dependencies in this way:

[image: Visual Studio NodeJs Solution]

**Update**: The source of my test code is published on [GitHub](https://github.com/rsciriano/nodejs-projectdeps)